# Drawing a simple 2D graph in java

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, java-2d

I got a below java code which plots a 2D graph where x axis has values 1,2,3,......20
and y axis has values 21,14,18..........18
The code works perfectly but the only problem is that the graph does not shows the corresponding x and y values on x axis and y axis respectively. I know it could be a small addition to the code. but i am new to java graphics and i am not able to figure out where to add the relevant code considering the time constraint.

```
/*Sample code */

public class GraphingData extends JPanel {

    int[] data = {
        21, 14, 18, 03, 86, 88, 74, 87, 54, 77,
        61, 55, 48, 60, 49, 36, 38, 27, 20, 18
    };
    final int PAD = 20;

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();
        // Draw ordinate.
        g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(PAD, PAD, PAD, h-PAD));
        // Draw abcissa.
        g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(PAD, h-PAD, w-PAD, h-PAD));
        // Draw labels.
        Font font = g2.getFont();
        FontRenderContext frc = g2.getFontRenderContext();
        LineMetrics lm = font.getLineMetrics("0", frc);
        float sh = lm.getAscent() + lm.getDescent();
        // Ordinate label.
        String s = "Average Byte Value";
        float sy = PAD + ((h - 2*PAD) - s.length()*sh)/2 + lm.getAscent();
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            String letter = String.valueOf(s.charAt(i));
            float sw = (float)font.getStringBounds(letter, frc).getWidth();
            float sx = (PAD - sw)/2;
            g2.drawString(letter, sx, sy);
            sy += sh;
        }
        // Abcissa label.
        s = "file blocks";
        sy = h - PAD + (PAD - sh)/2 + lm.getAscent();
        float sw = (float)font.getStringBounds(s, frc).getWidth();
        float sx = (w - sw)/2;
        g2.drawString(s, sx, sy);
        // Draw lines.
        double xInc = (double)(w - 2*PAD)/(data.length-1);
        double scale = (double)(h - 2*PAD)/getMax();
        g2.setPaint(Color.green.darker());
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length-1; i++) {
            double x1 = PAD + i*xInc;
            double y1 = h - PAD - scale*data[i];
            double x2 = PAD + (i+1)*xInc;
            double y2 = h - PAD - scale*data[i+1];
            g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(x1, y1, x2, y2));
        }
        // Mark data points.
        g2.setPaint(Color.red);
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            double x = PAD + i*xInc;
            double y = h - PAD - scale*data[i];
            g2.fill(new Ellipse2D.Double(x-2, y-2, 4, 4));
        }

    }

    private int getMax() {
        int max = -Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            if(data[i] > max)
                max = data[i];
        }
        return max;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new GraphingData());
        f.setSize(400,400);
        f.setLocation(200,200);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"..i am not able to figure out where to add the relevant code considering the time constraint."*  What 'time constraint'?

Comment: I mean i have some time constraints to go through the java tutorial and completely understand the graphics code and thus figure out where to add the code.

Comment: Perhaps you should leave this task for when you *do* have time.  People who offer free help typically expect you to have ti8me to refer to the Java Docs and tutorials to which they link.

Comment: I agree with you but as i already mentioned being new to java graphics it will take time for me to refer to java docs and understand its basics.As a part of my project i wanted to show some cool graphs of the data which i analysed.I could not have asked for this in the way i asked now if my project,s sole purpose is to show how to use  java graphics, my idea is to use the online available utilities to aide the representation aspect of my project.

Comment: [tag:jfreechart] might be a good choice; basic examples are cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jfreechart/info).

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Pay particular attention to the [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) section.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void drawGrid(Graphics g)
{
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    int rows = model.maxy-model.miny+1;
    int cols = model.maxx-model.minx+1;

    int colWidth = (getWidth()-paddingFromRight - ylabelWidth)/cols;
    int rowHeight = (getHeight()-xlabelHeight-headingHeight)/rows;

    int endX = ylabelWidth + cols * colWidth;
    int endY =  headingHeight + rows*rowHeight;

    for (int k = 0; k <= cols; k++)
    {
        g.drawLine(ylabelWidth+colWidth*k, headingHeight, ylabelWidth+colWidth*k, endY); //getHeight()-xlabelHeight
    }

    for (int k = 0; k <= rows;k++)
    {
        g.drawLine(ylabelWidth, headingHeight+rowHeight*k,endX, headingHeight+rowHeight*k);
    }
}

public void drawLines(Graphics g)
{
    ArrayList<Line> lines = model.getLines();
    Random random = new Random(50);
    for (int k = 0; k < lines.size(); k++)
    {
        g.setColor(new Color(255-50*k, 50*k, 2*50*k));
        //g.setColor(Color.red);
        drawLine(g, lines.get(k));
    }

}

public void drawLine(Graphics g, Line line)
{
    ArrayList<Point> points = line.points;
    for (int k = 0; k<points.size()-1;k++)
    {
        //scale up points
        Point p1 = points.get(k);
        Point p2 = points.get(k+1);
        g.drawLine(scaleUpX(p1.x), scaleUpY(p1.y), scaleUpX(p2.x), scaleUpY(p2.y));
        g.fillOval(scaleUpX(p1.x)-5, scaleUpY(p1.y)-5, 10, 10);
    }
    Point p1 = points.get(points.size()-1);
    g.fillOval(scaleUpX(p1.x)-5, scaleUpY(p1.y)-5, 10, 10);
}

public int scaleUpX(int x)
{
    int cols = model.maxx-model.minx+1;
    int colWidth = (getWidth()-paddingFromRight - ylabelWidth)/cols;

    return ylabelWidth+colWidth*x;
}
public int scaleUpY(int y)
{
    int rows = model.maxy-model.miny+1;
    int rowHeight = (getHeight()-xlabelHeight-headingHeight)/(rows);
    //int endY = getHeight()-xlabelHeight;
    int endY = headingHeight+rows*rowHeight;

    return endY - rowHeight*y;
}
public void drawLabels(Graphics g)
{
    Dimension d = getSize();
    //xlabel
    g.drawString(model.xlabel, d.width/2, d.height-xlabelHeight/4);
    //ylabel
    g.drawString(model.ylabel, 0+5, d.height/2);
    //xaxis
    int rows = model.maxy-model.miny+1;
    int cols = model.maxx-model.minx+1;

    int colWidth = (getWidth()-paddingFromRight - ylabelWidth)/cols;
    int rowHeight = (getHeight()-xlabelHeight-headingHeight)/rows;

    for (int k = 0;k<=cols;k++)
    {
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(model.minx+k), ylabelWidth+k*colWidth-5, rowHeight*rows+headingHeight+15);
    }
    //yaxis
    for (int k = 0;k<=rows;k++)
    {
        g.drawString(String.valueOf(model.maxy-k+1),ylabelWidth-15,headingHeight+k*rowHeight);
    }
    //heading
    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
    g.setFont(g.getFont().deriveFont((float)25.0));
    g.drawString(model.title, d.width/2-fm.stringWidth(model.title), headingHeight/2+headingHeight/4);
}
```

Comment: You should expand on this answer instead of only posting code; how does it answer the question? What is good/bad about your approach?